# Entity Framework 6 foreign key is null after removing and adding an item with the same key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple cache to quickly access some meta info for my application.

```
public class CacheList
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid Key1{ get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid Key0{ get; set; }

    public List<CacheItem> Items { get; set; }
    public List<CacheFolder> Folders { get; set; }
}

public class CacheItem
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid Key3 { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid Key4 { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I regularly update the whole Cache.

And to simplify it I always delete all items according to the current position and create new ones.

Example:

First I delete all corresponding Items. (The list itself also got deleted and created anew)

```
InsertContext.Items.RemoveRange(InsertContext.Items.Where(i => i.Key1 == key1.Id && i.ListId == key2.Id));
```

Then I add the new items to the list

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var dbitem = new CacheItem()
    { };
    dbList.Items.Add(dbitem);
}
```

Works almost perfect...

I just have a problem with the foreign key fields, they are null.

EF creates a insert statement which looks like this:

```
Insert .... VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, NULL, NULL)
```

If I cache a list for the first time it works fine. Starting with the second run it acts as described.

I am pretty sure it's because of the remove/add interaction but i don't really know how to solve the problem.

Of course I could only delete the items which no longer exist and update the rest, but that would create a some overhead I would like to prevent.

The whole procedure runs in one context with one `SaveChanges` at the end.

**EDIT:** Solved it: I finished all manipulation of the list and it's subelements before adding it to the context.

Comment: did you try calling SaveChanges() after the delete ? and then again after the insert? there is no harm in do it so.

Comment: i considered it, but apparently it is even more overhead than updating the existing items. But it is probably the way to go as i may have to do it anyway for big amounts of data.

Comment: so, it works when you do it that way?

Comment: I tried it, but it created to much exceptions to fix it quickly and I found a solution that works. Thanks for your help anyway.